# Loop through multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am having this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 165
            [id_format] => {num}
            [id_value] => 315
            [module_id] => 3
            [name] => Product 1
            [description] => Product 1
            [description_html] => 

    Product 1



            [qty] => 
            [module_row] => 2
            [module_group] => 
            [taxable] => 1
            [single_term] => 0
            [status] => active
            [company_id] => 1
            [prorata_day] => 
            [prorata_cutoff] => 
            [id_code] => 315
            [module_name] => Module
            [pricing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1903
                            [pricing_id] => 1903
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 1
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 23.4000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1904
                            [pricing_id] => 1904
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 2
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 46.8000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1905
                            [pricing_id] => 1905
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 3
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 70.2000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1906
                            [pricing_id] => 1906
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 4
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 93.6000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1907
                            [pricing_id] => 1907
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 5
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 117.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1908
                            [pricing_id] => 1908
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 6
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 140.4000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1909
                            [pricing_id] => 1909
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 7
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 163.8000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1910
                            [pricing_id] => 1910
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 8
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 187.2000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1911
                            [pricing_id] => 1911
                            [package_id] => 165
                            [term] => 9
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 210.6000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 168
            [id_format] => {num}
            [id_value] => 318
            [module_id] => 3
            [name] => Product 2
            [description] => Product 2
            [description_html] => 

    Product 2



            [qty] => 
            [module_row] => 20
            [module_group] => 
            [taxable] => 1
            [single_term] => 0
            [status] => active
            [company_id] => 1
            [prorata_day] => 
            [prorata_cutoff] => 
            [id_code] => 318
            [module_name] => Module
            [pricing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1993
                            [pricing_id] => 1993
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 1
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 34.5000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1994
                            [pricing_id] => 1994
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 2
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 69.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1995
                            [pricing_id] => 1995
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 3
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 103.5000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2006
                            [pricing_id] => 2006
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 4
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 138.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )
1
                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2017
                            [pricing_id] => 2017
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 5
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 172.5000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1998
                            [pricing_id] => 1998
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 6
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 207.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1999
                            [pricing_id] => 1999
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 7
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 241.5000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2000
                            [pricing_id] => 2000
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 8
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 276.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2001
                            [pricing_id] => 2001
                            [package_id] => 168
                            [term] => 9
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 310.5000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 169
            [id_format] => {num}
            [id_value] => 319
            [module_id] => 4
            [name] => Product 3
            [description] => Product 3
            [description_html] => 

    Product 3



            [qty] => 
            [module_row] => 3
            [module_group] => 
            [taxable] => 1
            [single_term] => 0
            [status] => active
            [company_id] => 1
            [prorata_day] => 
            [prorata_cutoff] => 
            [id_code] => 319
            [module_name] => Module
            [pricing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2023
                            [pricing_id] => 2023
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 1
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 15.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2024
                            [pricing_id] => 2024
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 2
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 30.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2025
                            [pricing_id] => 2025
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 3
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 45.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2026
                            [pricing_id] => 2026
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 4
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 60.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2027
                            [pricing_id] => 2027
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 5
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 75.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2028
                            [pricing_id] => 2028
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 6
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 90.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2029
                            [pricing_id] => 2029
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 7
                  1          [period] => year
                            [price] => 105.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2030
                            [pricing_id] => 2030
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 8
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 120.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2031
                            [pricing_id] => 2031
                            [package_id] => 169
                            [term] => 9
                            [period] => year
                            [price] => 135.0000
                            [setup_fee] => 0.0000
                            [cancel_fee] => 0.0000
                            [currency] => CAD
                        )

                )

        )
```

I would like to loop through the array, and only return the price of each product, for each term (1 year, 2 years and 3 years), in a table.

...but i am even not able to loop through the array.

Here is the code to call the API and return an std object :

```
$api = new Api($url, $user, $key);
$model = "packages";
$method = "getAllPackages";
$params = array('package_group_id'=>'2');
$response = $api->get($model, $method, $params);
```

**Here is what i tried  :**

the following returned an error : "Cannot use object of type STDClass as array"

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($response);$i++) {
    echo $response[$i]->pricing[$i]->price;
}
```

**I've also tried :**

```
$i = 165; 
$response->pricing[$i]->price;
```

**Also i tried :**

```
//loop the response
foreach($response as $obj){

    //check is it contains the pricing details
    if(is_array($obj->pricing)){
        //loop the price for each object
        foreach($obj->pricing as $pricingObj){
            //store the unique id and price
            $data[$pricingObj->id] = $pricingObj->price;
        }
    }
}

//print the result
print_r($data);
```

**And i tried as well  :**

```
foreach ($response as $item) {
    foreach ($item->pricing as $pricing) {
        var_dump($pricing->price);
    }
}
```

...but still : nothing is working for me.

Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: if that array is $responce, the first code should work

Comment: That's the problem... ...it doesn't work : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdObject as array

Comment: test your input data  https://eval.in/404613

Comment: Here `echo $response[$i]->pricing[$i]->price;` you use `$i` twice for different arrays. You probably need an extra loop for the pricing-array.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $api = new Api($url, $user, $key);
   $model = "packages";
   $method = "getAllPackages";
     $params = array('package_group_id'=>'2');
    $response = $api->get($model, $method, $params);
   foreach($response as $resp)
   {
                  foreach($resp->pricing as $key=>$pricing )
                  {
                        echo $pricing[$key]->price."<br>"; 
                  }
   }
```

please use to print price of each term.

Comment: I tried this, and nothing happen.  I am getting a blank page, and there is no errors in the apache error logs.

Comment: please try now as there is mistake in variable $resp

Comment: Thank you.  ...but i already saw the error, and i fixed it in my code before i replied it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the response like this. This code will works only the price object id is unique across the object.

```
<?php 
$data = array();
$api = new Api($url, $user, $key);
$model = "packages";
$method = "getAllPackages";
$params = array('package_group_id'=>'2');
$response = $api->get($model, $method, $params);

//loop the response
foreach($response as $obj){

    //check is it contains the pricing details
    if(is_array($obj->pricing)){
        //loop the price for each object
        foreach($obj->pricing as $pricingObj){
            //store the unique id and price
            $data[$pricingObj->id] = $pricingObj->price;
        }
    }
}

//print the result
print_r($data);
```

Comment: this returned a notice : "Notice: Undefined variable: data"

Comment: $data = array(); have you add this line at the top as it is in the answer. Check the first line. If answer is right then accept it

Comment: Hi.  ok. i just saw it, and i gave another try.  It doesn't return any notice this time, but the array is empty.  The output was  `Array ( ) `

Comment: if your response object have data then it's should work. or else you have to check your api results only. print_r($response) and see your result